# Pre populated select in Angular 6 from API data

Tags: angular6, dropdown

I populating a select dropdown in Angular 6 from data returned from a resolver. Im subscribing to this.route.data and storing the data 'teamMembers' in an array.

Then i iterate over the array in my template with:

```
        <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'highlighted' : messageForm.controls.MessageTo.disabled === false}" required>
      <label>To</label>
      <select class="form-control" formControlName="MessageTo" required>
        <option [ngValue]="member" *ngFor="let member of teamMembers">{{ member.User.EmailID }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Im prepopulating the select with data returned from API with:

```
this.messageForm = this.fb.group({
    MessageTo: [{value: this.thisMessage.ToUser.EmailID, disabled: false}]
  });
```

I can see the data in the select dropdown in the browser, BUT ONLY once i click on the select. If I dont click on the select then it just shows blank as though nothing is in the select???

[image]

I want it to show the prepopulated Email set in the component.ts file.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, sorted it. I added a new property of "originator" which was equal to the value of my default teamMemberGuid, to my class, and bound the value of that via [(ngModel)]="originator" on my select. Works a treat